# why is $\omega^n \neq 0$ for a nondegenerate 2 form $\omega$.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $\omega$ be a nondegenerate alternating $2$-form on an $2n$-dimesional Vectorspace $V$, meaning that for all nonzero $v \in V$ the map $w \mapsto \omega(v,w)$ is not identically zero.

Why is the nth power $\omega^n = \omega \wedge \dots \wedge \omega \neq 0$?

Every textbook i have looked at says this is very easy, but i do not see it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer of Jason DeVito shows that $\omega$ need not be closed for this to hold. The nondegeneracy condition just is equivalent to the condition that $V$ has an even dimension and $\omega^n$ is nowhere vanishing on $V$. So this answeres your question completely.